# Can't add multiple pseudo-classes to a :not() pseudo-class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I try to apply a style to every elements but the first and the last one. There's many way to do it I know. But I'm facing up a weird behavior (I believe?).

If I use the `:not()` pseudo-class in assiociation with `:last-child` for example, it will work fine. But as soon as I add a second pseudo-class (let say `:first-child`) that will not work.

Here we go

```css
.div-list {
  width:100px;
  height:400px;
}

.div-list div {
  width:25%;
  height:25%;
  background-color:green;
}
.div-list div:not(:last-child) {
  background-color:red;
}

.div-list div:not(:last-child,:first-child) {
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='div-list'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Note that I'm aware of the [standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-classes) and apparently my syntax is "theoricaly" correct. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple classes selectors to `:not` is only supported in CSS selectors level 4 and it doesn't work in all browsers. It currently only works in `Safari`, instead you could use multiple `:not`

```
.div-list div:not(:last-child):not(:first-child) {
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Check the [`browser support doc`](http://css4.rocks/negation-pseudo-class.php)

Comment: that makes sense. I knew multiple selector inside a `:not()` are not well supported, I didn't knew that's so advanced that it's not supported anywhere yet haha. Thank you for this very clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rather use this selector that uses 2 not selectors, which is like saying not the last child and not the first child :

```
.div-list div:not(:last-child):not(:first-child)
```

```css
.div-list {
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
}

.div-list div {
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: green;
}

.div-list div:not(:last-child) {
  background-color: red;
}

.div-list div:not(:last-child):not(:first-child) {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='div-list'>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```